# How to setup a dimmer with 4 terminal

Tags: dimmer, setup

I have a dimmer with 2 terminals the configuration was easy,
now I have tried t replace it, unfortunately the replacement has a different terminals configuration without any indication on each terminal.

See the pictures

[image]

```
Brown wire=main phase line
```

here the circuit board
[image]

Any idea about how to setup it is appreciated.

EDIT
Searching the name of the component seems ZC11000 but I have found only Russian and Chinese resources without any technical sheet.

Comment: Read the Fine Manual that you should have received with the product.

Comment: Are there any markings on, or next to the terminals? One might be Earth, and the other three might be for two way switching.

Comment: @PeterBennett Should be clear that there is NO manual. I received only a plastic bag with this. I'm not so dumb to open a thread here with a manual in my hands

Comment: @Ian Bland there is no mark, all terminals haven't any symbol or indication

Comment: Lol then how are you supposed to know how to use it? What about where you purchased it from (a website perhaps could have details or a downloadable spec sheet/cut sheet)?

Comment: If you didn't get any instructions with the dimmer, ask the supplier for them.  We are not the supplier's support dept.  (And you haven't given any information that would allow us to identify the dimmer or supplier, so anything we say would be a wild guess.)

Comment: I have already sent a message but still no answer. He is an Asian supplier, and strangely in his store thousand of people reviewed this item positively apparently without any difficult to understand how the hell these terminals work. I haven't idea if these kind of voltage regulators are so popular in Asia that they don't need any explanation.

Comment: Okay, give us  picture of the underside (the circuit board tracks), that might give us a clue. Back in my day as an electrician I used to somehow have to figure things like this out when a householder plonked something in my hand and demanded that it be installed. Also, does the pot have a switching action, that is can you push it in and out to actuate a switch? Have you got a multimeter?

Comment: @IanBland I have added a picture with circuit board. I have a multimeter but not at this moment (I have to replace battery but now is night in my country, no store available)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it belongs in Home Improvement

Comment: How many electronics and electrics experts are there in the wallpapering forum? Anyway, the two outer terminals are not connected to the circuit and just looped together, so the middle two are the active ones. I'm guessing at terminal 2 (from the top, counting from the left) is live in (brown) and terminal three is the dimmed output (blue).

Comment: @ScottSeidman Why home improvement??? Is a question about voltage regulator configuration.

Comment: The outer terminals are presumably for looping a neutral if you've got one. So it would be wired Neutral, Live, Switched Live, Neutral (to light).

Comment: @IanBland So you guess I have to connect the phase1(my brown wire) to 2nd, the dimmed phase to 3rd and attach another looping neutral wire bridge between 1st and 4th terminal?

Comment: Yes to the first part, no to the second. The outer terminals are already looped together, so if you haven't got a neutral ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I'll wager a proper answer before somebody closes the question. The terminals are, viewed from the top, from the Left (terminals at bottom of view)

1) Neutral

2) Live

3) Switched Live to lamp

4) Neutral to lamp

Comment: Let me know  how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not setup this device at all (except in a lab).

Two reasons:

1. Your insurance will investigate CE or FCC signs before paying anything if it burns down your home. I'm pretty sure what they will find.
2. You do not even have manufacturer instructions to follow. Looking at the circuit, I get the impression that it is **not** intended for 240VAC at all. I do not see a power inductor there.

I would be curious what the waveform on the output is and how the device looks in thermal image after 2 minutes use.

Comment: There isn't any "CE certification". A CE mark just means that the manufacturer believes that the item complies with regulations, which frequently is just guesswork, and that's when the manufacturer actually cares. I've seen much worse than this, which is why electrical accessories are supposed to be installed in such a way that if they catch fire, nothing else will (basically, a non-combustible enclosure).

Comment: @IanBland Agreed, I will edit this. But tell me, how is this circuit supposed to work? Drop the voltage in a power semiconductor? What will happen, if you dimm a 100W bulb to 50%, how hot will the heatsink be? I get the impression that this can be used for a model railroad, but not for mains.

Comment: I'm presuming that that's a triac bolted to the heatsink with the usual crude trigger circuit. Because it's switching, the heat generated is usually tolerable. These sorts of dimmers at least in the UK are meant to be mounted in a suitably deep box but I've seen them crammed into shallow ones pressing on the wires. The build quality of electrical accessories is frequently appalling. We rely on the circuit breaker/RCD tripping when they fail, to pre-empt starting a fire. Apologies if I seemed a bit "sharp" in my comment above by the way.

Comment: @IanBland You're welcome. Nevertheless, I will stick with my recommendation, because I personally would not use this. An RCD will do nothing if there is no ground, a breaker will help if it creates a short before it sets on a fire.